# osgVisualizer in OMNeT

Tags: omnet++, inet

In MobilityShowcase.ned example, I get this error:

`Submodule osgVisualizer: No module type named 'IntegratedOsgVisualizer' found that implements module interface inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer (not in the loaded NED files?), at /home/nihan/Documents/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.4/src/inet/visualizer/common/IntegratedVisualizer.ned:26 -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) MobilityShowcase.visualizer (id=2), during network setup`

I've seen that osg directory looks like this in OMNeT:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable OSG visualizer in the inet project:

1. Right click on inet project
2. Select properties
3. Select and expand OMNET++ from the menu
4. Select project feature
5. Check *visualization OSG (3D)*. Also you can enable *visualization OSG (3D) show cases* in case you want to run the show cases.

[image: Screenshot of project properties]